# SQL_INJECTION_JDBC Findbugs when loading from file

Tags: java, sql, callable-statement

I have an anonymous procedure that I am getting with a StatementLoader and passing it to a CallableStatement. However FindBugs identifies this as being vulnerable to SQL Injection (SQL_INJECTION_JDBC). If I create a static method that returns the procedure as a string it is fine.

Is there a way I can use the statement loader without the sql injection bug popping up?

Example:

```
StatementLoader stmt = StatementLoader.getLoader(MyClass.class, connection);    
try (final CallableStatement callable = connection.prepareCall(stmt.load("mySqlCode"))) {...
```

Comment: We need to see some of your code in order to ascertain whether it is a *bona fide* SQL injection opportunity.

Comment: Updated question with the exact statement that causes the bug. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your programming merely loads an SQL statement from an external source and executes it, it *is* a bona-fide SQL injection opportunity.  The SQL statement should be a constant within the program, using parameter-substitution to provide values when executing it.  The bug-catcher is correct – you should rewrite this code at once.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have gone with the a literal string and sanitized parameters as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to clarify *exactly* what I meant by "parameters," since the OP's latest comment used the word, "sanitized."

SQL permits the use of "parameters" in an SQL statement – indicated by question-marks that are *not* literal-strings – such as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?
```

Each and every time the statement is executed, a value for each parameter must be supplied, usually as an array of values.  *(Of course, most actual database APIs are more friendly, letting you conveniently "name" your parameters.)*  So, the parameters **are never part of the SQL string**.

The SQL statement is parsed ("prepared") only once, and the database engine knows that parameter-values must then be supplied each and every time the statement is executed.  The query-engine will take and use those parameter-values directly; it will not re-evaluate the SQL. *(Which, by the way, is noticeably more efficient!)*

The *binary* values that you provide are used as-is.  You don't even have to convert them to character form.  Specifically, **you *don't* "sanitize" them**!  If you provide a value such as `FOO%20BAR` to some character-type column in an `INSERT` statement, you'll find a **9**-character literal value being inserted into your database:  `F-O-O-%-2-0-B-A-R`.  "Those are the 9 characters that you gave me, so that's what I did."

(Database systems, and interfaces to the same, vary in their handling of data-types such as "date.")